# How to add a TimePicker control to a Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, timepicker

I'm trying to implement a time picker like is shown in the below screenshot but I can't find the control in the Windows 8 Phone toolbox.

I'm aiming to format it as hours,minutes & seconds for a stop watch application.

Does anyone have any idea how it could it be implemented or if its available?

I tried the following to no avail as visual studio doesn't recognize the time picker control:

```
<TimePicker x:Name="timePicker" Header="Time:" ClockIdentifier="24HourClock"
                Margin="5" TimeChanged="timePicker_TimeChanged" />
```

[image: Time picker]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That control does not exist in standard controls for Windows Phone 8.  You only have it available for Windows Phone 8.1 and later (once there is a later).

Comment: i.e. the picker you show *is* the 8.1 picker.  The picker in the toolbox for <8.1 is a different picker

Comment: Is there an alternative toolkit I can include that has a similar control for Win Phone 8?